# Bigint issue when will be displayed at template

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a MySQL database with a `bigint` field but when I'm using on `cakephp` the number `697483533702444` is being displayed as `2147483647`

Comment: Switch to using a 64-bit version of PHP

Comment: for now this is not possible

Comment: Then you're kind of scuppered.... change your database to use an int rather than a bigint, or a guid if it's a PK field

Comment: Is not PK field is a facebook_uid

Comment: Then store it as a string (varchar), not as bigint

Comment: To add on to what @Mark Baker said, as a general rule, only store integers when you need to do math on them (`sum()` is math). Especially since Facebook could change their uid format to a hexidecimal number or a random alphanumeric string.

Comment: conclusion.. the better thing to do is change the field type to varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either use a 64bit version of PHP or store your data in the database as a `CHAR(20)` or `VARCHAR(20)`

Answer (score 0):

I cant write comment (missing points), but I experienced some Problems with signed and unsigned Integers and quite similar results. Please try changing signed and unsigned in the database.